# Custom ScrollBar Style Within ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollbar, controltemplate

## What I'm Trying to Achieve:

I've created a ListBox with a custom control template using Blend. I want to be able to change it's scrollbar. In blend, I've tried editing the scrollviewers style/ template, but the scrollviewer would look weird, and it wouldn't scroll the items. Also, I've created a style for a ScrollBar Control (in Blend), but I can't seem to use it with my ListBox. If there is a way I can "swap it" with the original boring one, that would be awesome. Thanks in advance. This is the what I have now (the ScrollBar in this example is the one I created, just dragged over the ListBox, so it doesn't really work):

[image]

## XAML for ListBox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF141414" Opacity="0.995" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
            <ListBoxItem x:Name="LBIMouseLeftButtonDown" Background="#FFE62828" Content="MouseLeftButtonDown" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBoxItemStyle}" Selected="LBIMouseLeftButtonDown_Selected"/>
            <ListBoxItem Content="MouseLeftButtonUp" Style="{DynamicResource ToolBoxItemStyle}"/>
        </ListBox>
```